# Error from alpha vantage api after requesting data for a few times

Tags: python, api

So I have a code that is running well, the code loop over a bunch of stock symbols and pulling data from this API: `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo`
(i got an apikey this is just a demo).
once the loop hit the **sixth** symbol I get an error like this:
`KeyError: 'Time Series (Daily)'`.
the strange thing is if I run it again from the sixth symbol (so the sixth become the first symbol) I don't get this error for the symbol but I will get it for the new sixth symbol in the loop.
for example, I got `[AAPL, NFLX, NTES, RXN, VRTU, ZTO, BABA, BEST, BAM, FB, AMZN,TSLA]` as my symbol list. then it would show me error for `ZTO`, after I got my info for the first five in my list the list would look like this `[ZTO, BABA, BEST, BAM, FB, AMZN, TSLA]` then i will get my error on `AMZN`.

It seems to that it isn't related to the error that it is showing and something to do with the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a time delay to your code since on the free key you can only do 5 requests per minute than it times you out.